# Posgresql vs Mysql for SqlAlchemy based RESTful API?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I am developing a RESTful API, using SQLAlchemy ORM middleware sitting on top of a Flask App written in python. Everything is hosted on AWS. In terms of the backend database, currently I am using MySql but am considering switching to Postgresql.

At the moment one consideration is the migrations process. As far as I understand, transactions are supported by Postgre, and not with Mysql, and this leaves migrations vulnerable to being stuck in a semi-migrated state when using MySql, which could otherwise be 'transacted' using Postgre -- leading to a more robust procedure. If the above predicate is incorrect, then someone please let me know.

I am asking here if anyone has made this decision before, and what was decided and whether this was a good decision or not in 20/20 hindsight. I found this article quite good ([CLICK HERE](https://benchling.engineering/move-fast-and-migrate-things-how-we-automated-migrations-in-postgres-d60aba0fc3d4)), and would appreciate any further insight.

Basically I am trying to make a sound and educated decision early on in my development cycle.

Comment: Ok, thats good to know. Cheers.

Comment: PostgreSQL supports transactions for schema changes (add/remove tables, columns, constraints, ...) but I don't think MySQL does. I think your point about transactions and migrations is real when you're talking about schema changes rather than data changes.